# Return BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I ran into a problem which I don't have any idea what could be happening.

I have a class which calls a second class to send a command throught ssh and return the result.

The result is a BufferedReader, and then this result is treated in my first class.

First class:

```
  .
  .
  .       
  String command = "ping " + ip + " -c 1";
  BufferedReader result = instance.sendCommand(command);
         // close only after all commands are sent
         System.out.println("out of sshManager result : "+result);
         System.out.println("out of sshManager line : "+result.readLine());
         String line = null;
         while ((line = result.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println("out of sshManager line: "+line);
         }
```

Second class:

```
public BufferedReader sendCommand(String command) throws JSchException, IOException {
        //StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();    

        Channel channel = sesConnection.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.connect();

        InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("This is in sshmanager SSHManager: " + commandOutput);
        result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(commandOutput));            
        String line = null;
        System.out.println(" sshmanager result : " + result());
        System.out.println(" sshmanager result line : " + result.readLine());

        while ((line = result.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("in sshmanager: " + line);
        }

        System.out.println("in sshmanager result : " + result);
        channel.disconnect();
        return result;        
}
```

Result:

```
This is in sshmanager SSHManager: com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream@40d5bd18
sshmanager result : java.io.BufferedReader@10a5ae6e
sshmanager result line : PING 192.168.11.11 (192.168.11.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
in sshmanager: From 192.168.11.77 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
in sshmanager: 
in sshmanager: --- 192.168.11.11 ping statistics ---
in sshmanager: 1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3006ms
in sshmanager: 
in sshmanager result: java.io.BufferedReader@10a5ae6e
out of sshManager result: java.io.BufferedReader@10a5ae6e
out of sshManager line: null
```

The objects is well created in my second class but I don't know why, when I try to manage the object in my first class the content is null.

Do you have any idea what is worng?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BufferedReader` has already read through the file when it is returned to the first method.  You may want to return a `List<String>` containing the contents of the file instead of the `BufferedReader`.

```
public List<String> sendCommand(String command) throws JSchException, IOException {
        List<String> lines = new LinkedList<String>();
        Channel channel = sesConnection.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.connect();

        InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
        result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(commandOutput));            
        String line = null;

        while ((line = result.readLine()) != null) {
           lines.add(line);
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        return lines;        
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works and i think is a good idea since i have to keep those data for other operations. Btw there is something I dont understand  with BufferedReader, because if I commented the `readlince` in the second class and remove the while, the result still being null. However, if I keep `System.out.println(" sshmanager result line : " + result.readLine());` I can read the result in my first class without the first line, it's a bit weird, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It's all coming from the concept of streaming.

Once you advance through the stream in the "second class", you actually consume the stream. So, at the moment when you return it to the "first class", the stream is entirely consumed. Therefore, you cannot stream anything anymore.

Please note, that even if you wrap the stream into a reader, the read operations (e.g. `readLine`) are forwarded to the stream.

Answer (score 1):

A bufferred reader is like a string of bytes that you can read from **once**.

Your basic problem is that inside the function you've already extracted the text from the reader, so when you try again you just get null (because the reader is **NOW** empty).